# immediate_failed error in google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-signin

I would like to signin in Google Analytics to get data. I do this:

var CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXX';

var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'];

```
        function authorize(event) {

          var useImmdiate = event ? false : true;
          var authData = {
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            scope: SCOPES,
            immediate: useImmdiate
          };
          console.log("AUTHDATA", authData)
          gapi.auth.authorize(authData, function(response) {
            console.log("RESPONSE", response)
            var authButton = document.getElementById('auth-button');
            if (response.error) {
              console.log("ERROR --->", response.error)
            }
            else {
              queryAccounts();
            }
          });
        }
```

And it goes throw error. AuthData is this:

```
authData = {
    client_id: XXXXXXX,
    gsiwebsdk:"1",
    hl: undefined,
    include_granted_scopes: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:1337",
    proxy: "oauth2relay690667120",
    redirect_uri: "postmessage",
    response_type: "token",
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly",
    state: "320683367|0.4055793373"
}
```

And the response object is this:

```
response = {
   client_id: XXXXXX,
   cookie_policy: undefined,
   error: "immediate_failed",
   error_subtype: "access_denied",
   expires_at: "1493276419",
   expires_in: "86400",
   g_user_cookie_policy: undefined,
   issued_at: "1493190019",
   response_type: "token",
   scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly",
   state: "",
   status: {
      google_logged_in: false,
      method: null,
      signed_in: false
   }
}
```

I have this script:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=authorize"></script>
```

And this meta:

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="XXXXXX">
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly">
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried with `immediate: false` ?

Comment: Thanks!! it works!

Comment: But I would like to get events from google analytics too.